# Realm DB Realm.asObservable() emits results twice

Tags: android, database, realm, rx-java

I use RxJava and Realm DB for my application. When I query the data in the Realm and call `Realm.asObservable()`,The RealmResult emits 2 times.

```
public class JustTest extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TEST";
    private Realm realm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.where(Group.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
                .subscribe(new Action1<RealmResults<Group>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(RealmResults<Group> groups) {
                        XLog.d(TAG, "Realm launch group result, size " + groups.size());
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Log:

```
TEST: Realm emits group result, size 0
TEST: Realm emits group result, size 1
```

Comment: `.asObservable().skip(1)`

Answer (score 5):

That is by design, as Realm emits a placeholder object immediately if you subscribe to it. If you are only interested in the first "real" result you can do something like this:

```
realm.where(Foo.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
  .filter(obj::isLoaded) // isLoaded is true when query is completed
  .first() // Only get the first result and then complete
  .subscribe(...)
```

This is not immediately clear from the current documentation, but we are in the process of updating the JavaDoc to explain this better: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2201

Comment: I can't use 'first' because I use this in my RxBinding. In some of my code, there are still bugs.

Comment: I can't use 'first' because I use this in my RxBinding.

Comment: Why not? `realm.where(Group.class).findAllAsync().asObservable().filter(..).first().subscribe(...)`  should be perfectly possible?

Comment: Alternatively you can create your own `RxObservableFactory` and do it there: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#rxjava

Comment: I use `flatMap` to convert my `ViewClick` to `RealmResult`, so when I use `first` I can only click my view for once.

Comment: I don't get the first() ? That will give you only the first change according to the [Rx marble diagram](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) which will render the whole concept of observing changes useless.
Omitting it gives me duplicate events, even when filtering for isLoaded, in turn rendering distinctUntilChanged and similar filters useless